# Splitting a huge dataframe into smaller dataframes and writing to files using SPARK(python)

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading a (5gb compressed file) into memory (aws), creating a dataframe(in spark) and trying to split it into smaller dataframes based on 2 column values. Eventually i want to write all these sub-sets into their respective files.

I just started experimenting in spark and just getting used to the data structures. The approach I was trying to follow was something like this.

- read the file
- sort it by the 2 columns (still not familiar with repartitioning and do not know if it will help)
- identify unique list of all values of those 2 columns
- iterate through this list
  -- create smaller dataframes by filtering using the values in list
  -- writing to files

  ```
   df.sort("DEVICE_TYPE", "PARTNER_POS")
  df.registerTempTable("temp")
  grp_col = sqlContext.sql("SELECT DEVICE_TYPE, PARTNER_POS FROM temp GROUP BY  DEVICE_TYPE, PARTNER_POS")
  print(grp_col)
  ```

I do not believe this are cleaner and more efficient ways of doing this. I need to write this to files as there are etls which get kicked off in parallel based on the output. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

If it's okay that the subsets are nested in a directory hierarchy, then you should consider using spark's builtin partitioning:

```scala
df.write.partitionBy("device_type","partner_pos")
  .json("/path/to/root/output/dir")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I want to store it as tab delimited files in the same directory with partner_pos & device_type added to the filenames.. as of now this partition by does not allow for that kind of flexibility from what i read.. My production spark version is 1.6.2.. Should i consider spark streaming, but the source file is gzipped and i do not how it would work